# arduino: why is my function not running

Tags: arduino

```
float result_temp = 0.0;
float original_temp = 0.0; 

void setup() {
get_temp();
}
void loop() {
}
float get_temp() 
{                                                                                     
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    int analogValue = analogRead(2);                               
    float temperature = (5.0 * 100.0 * analogValue) / 1024;
    result_temp += temperature;               
    original_temp = analogRead(pin_temp);       
  delay(100);                                                                                            
}
result_temp /= 50; 
return result_temp;  
}
```

I want to run it one time (at the start) why isn't it working?

Comment: You may want to add the language tag instead of the meta-tag [tag:function].

Comment: I suspect your code is working perfectly.  The code you have posted retrieves the temperature using `get_temp()` but then does nothing with it.  It doesn't send it over the serial port or have some physical output do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop MCU running by putting it into sleep mode after execution of your code, [example](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode) . Another way (and it is simpler) is to put your code in setup and it will run only once. Here is starting point:

```
void setup(){
 // put your code here
 // ...
 while(1);// infinite loop
}
void loop(){
 // empty
}
```